# Python list string comparison not working

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create a small python program that takes a list of first names and last names, creates a usernames in the format FirstInitial . LastName (optional number to differentiate similar names), example P.Test16. It then compares them to a list of existing usernames, as well as all other newly generated usernames and makes them all unique by incrementing the number on the end. 
However while it can compare new usernames to existing usernames it can't compare them to other new usernames, for example I currently already have a user names "j.moore" and I also have tow new users who will have a usernames j.moore, so both have usernames "j.moore1" after the first run in the while loop, but it won't then make the second one "j.moore2" in the second run. below is my code

```
while len(intakearray) > 0:
    nonuniqueusers = []
    for row in intakearray:
        if (row[2] not in usersarray) and (row[2] not in uniqueusers):
            if count > 0:
                print(row)
            uniqueusers.append(row)
        else:
            nonuniqueusers.append(row)
            if args.verbose >= 1:
                conflicts += 1
                if args.verbose == 2:
                    conflictingnames.append(row[2])
    for row in nonuniqueusers:
        newname = row[2]
        if count >= 1:
            newname = row[2][0:-1]
        newname += str(count + 1)
        row[2] = newname
    intakearray = nonuniqueusers
    count += 1
```

Comment: That's far from a [mcve]! So it it hard to guess what your code actually does and should do. Build an example list with some names, write simple code that tries to transform the list and show it explaining what you obtain and what you would like to obtain. You will certainly get more (good) answers :-)

Comment: @Serge Ballesta sorry, I should have been a little more clear about the code, however Christopher Bohme has answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user is unique you store the complete `row` from the `intakearray` in `uniqueusers` (line 7 of your code listing):

```
uniqueusers.append(row)
```

However, when you check whether a user name is unique, you check whether the username in `row[2]` is in `uniqueusers` (line 4 in your code):

```
if (row[2] not in usersarray) and (row[2] not in uniqueusers):
```

When you change line 7 from `uniqueusers.append(row)` to `uniqueusers.append(row[2])` your code should work as expected.

As your example does not says anything about the contents of the `usersarray` you should check that there is not the same mismatch between having full rows in there and checking only for the user name in the if-statement above.